# Show that $ f_n $ is discontinuous at $ \mathbb Q $.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

For every $n\in\mathbb N$ and $x\in [0,1]$, let $f_n$ define by $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} 1, &\text{ if } x=p/q\in\mathbb Q,\gcd(p,q)=1\ \text{and}\ q\leq n; \\ 0, &\text{ other case } \end{cases}.$$

What I want to prove is that the points of discontinuity of this function have a measure of $ 0 $ according to Lebesgue. The set of discontinuity points $ D_{f_n} $ of this function is $ D_{f_n} = [0,1] \cap \mathbb Q $, which is a countable set and therefore has a measure of $ 0 $ according to Lebesgue.

I have tried to guide myself with this page for the test: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function".

But there the function has the change of $ 1 / q $, and they use the Archimedean property for that, and here everything gets upset because I don't have that here. Who help me?

Comment: Isn't the set of points with $f_n(x)=1$ finite for each $n$?

Comment: That what should I try right? Although the set where the $ 1 $ function is made is $ [0,1] \cap \mathbb Q $, and that is not finite.

Comment: But you are just working with $f_n$ arent you? or what is $f$?

Comment: The function $f_n$ is only discontinuous in a finite number of values.

Comment: If I'm only working with $ f_n $. But how is it proved to be discontinuous at finite points?

Comment: For example, with $n=4$, the discontinuities are at $0$, $1$, $1/2$, $1/3$, $2/3$, $1/4$, $3/4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $n$ the set $A_n=\{\frac{p}{q} | \quad 0\leq \frac{p}{q}\leq1 \text{ and } \}$ is a finite set.

Your function $f_n$ is just the indicator function of $A_n$, so we can just prove this lemma:

Let $A$ be a finite subset of $[0,1]$, then the indicator function of $A$ (which we denote $1_A$) is discontinuous exactly at the points of $A$.

Proof: We first prove $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}1_A(x) = 0$ for all $x_0\in A$. To do this, given $\varepsilon>0$, we can just take $\delta$ equal to the smallest distance between $x_0$ and the closest point of $A$ that isn't $x_0$.

Once we have found these limits it is clear that the function does not coincide with the limit exactly at the points that belong to $A$.

I now suspect that maybe you have to prove that the set $D$ of points that are discontinuities for at least on of the functions has measure $0$, and in this case we can just use the above to see that $D=\mathbb Q$, and so indeed it does have measure $0$.

Comment: Did you finish writing your answer or are you missing something, because you have something of an incomplete limit, or are you not finished writing?

Comment: I'm finished${}{}$

Comment: I am trying to understand your delta choice. Could you explain that to me, if it's not too much of a hassle.

Comment: $1_A(x) = 0$ for all $x\not\in A$. So if the point is closer than the closest element of $A$ it is not in $A$.

Comment: That way you grab $ \delta = \min \{| x_0-x |: x \neq x_0 \} $. Right? But with that delta, how do you verify that $ | f (x) | <\epsilon $?.

Comment: No, I take $\delta=\min\{x_0-x| x\in A, x\neq x_0\}$ and then you get $|f(x)| = 0 $ because $f(x)=0$, because $x\not\in A$. Also I wasn't using the variable $f$ I was using $1_A$ but I guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: Why have you not accepted an answer for any of your questions?

Comment: How well accepted?  What do you mean?

Comment: the checkmark option next to an answer. You are supposed to click it when you want to accept someones answer

Comment: I did not know that this existed, I never realized that you had to accept the answers of others.  Thank you for informing me of that.

Answer (score 0):

Your function has at most finitely many discontinuities. Specifically, all points $x = p/q$ where $f(x) = 1$ will have $0 \leq p, q \leq n$. So you'll have at most $n^2$ points. (More precisely, you'll have about $\sum_{m \leq n} \varphi(m) \sim \frac{6}{\pi^2} n^2$ points).

As you have finitely many such points, their measure is $0$.